# Android: List view with drop down detailed view (not spinner or not expandable list view)

Tags: android, android-listview, drop-down-menu

Hi i'm trying to do list view with drop down detailed view. For example see this [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3lrG.png). When we click any list view then it display the detailed view (with respect to the list view)like [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gACdu.png). This detailed view not like expandable list view or spinner. Please help me to do this

Comment: this is very much achievable from expendable list view then why you don't want `expendable list view`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout this github i just setup https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/ExpandableListView

The idea is hide and show the view using visibility, here is some code illustrating the point:

First setup your Item class or whatever object you want to use (simple pojo implementing Parcelable)

```
public class Item implements Parcelable{

public String title;
public String description;
public boolean isExpanded;

public Item(){}

public Item(Parcel in){
    title = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
    isExpanded = in.readInt() == 1;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeInt(isExpanded ? 1 : 0);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Item>(){
    @Override
    public Item createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Item(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Item[size];
    }
};
}
```

then create your adapter:

```
public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

List<Item> items;
Context context;

public class Row{
    AppCompatTextView mTvTitle;
    AppCompatTextView mTvDescription;
    FrameLayout mFlWrapper;
    ImageView mIvArrow;
}

public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items){
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Row theRow;

    if(convertView == null){
        theRow = new Row();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        theRow.mFlWrapper = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fl_wrapper);
        theRow.mTvTitle = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        theRow.mTvDescription = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        theRow.mIvArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);

        convertView.setTag(theRow);
    }else{

        theRow = (Row) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Update the View
    Item item = items.get(position);
    if(item.isExpanded){
        theRow.mFlWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        theRow.mIvArrow.setRotation(180f);
    }else{
        theRow.mFlWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        theRow.mIvArrow.setRotation(0f);
    }

    theRow.mTvTitle.setText(item.title);
    theRow.mTvDescription.setText(item.description);


    // return the view
    return convertView;
}
}
```

finally in your Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
    ExpandableAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

    lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ExpandableAdapter adapter = (ExpandableAdapter) parent.getAdapter();

            Item item = (Item) adapter.getItem(position);
            if(item != null){
                if(item.isExpanded){
                    item.isExpanded = false;

                }else{
                    item.isExpanded = true;
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}


private ExpandableAdapter getAdapter(){

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Item item = new Item();
        item.title = "Title Item " + i;
        item.description = "Description for Title Item "+ i;
        item.isExpanded = false;

        items.add(item);
    }

    return new ExpandableAdapter(this, items);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi i'm new to android. If you don't mind can you provide the sample code by using eclipse (ADT)

Comment: @kiran please use Android studio going forward as this is the official Android IDE, but you can just create MainActivity.java, ExpandableListAdapter.java, and Item.java then copy the code into your classes from the github. You will need to add the support library as a dependency though or change` AppCompatTextView` to `TextView`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i'm trying to achieve this, by using your instructions. As you said i'll use IDE in future

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to "inner_class7": According to the "inner_class7" i got the answer but by using his code i have to achieve two requirements

**Requirement 1:** When we clicking on the description the expanded view is closing but i don't want to close the view

**Requirement 2:** I want to close the previous view (if exists) when extending the new view

To achieve above two requirements, update "inner_class7" code according to the below steps

**Step 1:** Create **Global.java**

```
public class Global {

  public static Item itemGlobal;

}
```

**Step 2:** Update **MainActivity.java**

```
import static com.app.listviewdrop.Global.itemGlobal;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_drop);


    ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
    ExpandableAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

    lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ExpandableAdapter adapter = (ExpandableAdapter) parent.getAdapter();

            Item item = (Item) adapter.getItem(position);

            if(item != null){
                if(item.isExpanded){
                    item.isExpanded = false;

                }else{
                    item.isExpanded = true;

                    itemGlobal = (Item)adapter.getItem(position);
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}


private ExpandableAdapter getAdapter(){

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Item item = new Item();
        item.title = "Title Item " + i;
        item.description = "Description for Title Item "+ i;
        item.isExpanded = false;

        items.add(item);
    }

    return new ExpandableAdapter(this, items);
}
}
```

**Step3:** Update **ExpandableAdapter.java**

```
import static com.YOUR PACKAGE NAME.itemGlobal;


public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<Item> items;
Context context;
// List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();


public class Row {
    AppCompatTextView mTvTitle;
    AppCompatTextView mTvDescription;
    FrameLayout mFlWrapper;
    ImageView mIvArrow;
}

public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Row theRow;

    if (convertView == null) {
        theRow = new Row();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        theRow.mFlWrapper = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fl_wrapper);
        theRow.mTvTitle = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        theRow.mTvDescription = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        theRow.mIvArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);

        convertView.setTag(theRow);


        theRow.mFlWrapper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    } else {

        theRow = (Row) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Update the View
    Item item = items.get(position);


    if (item.isExpanded) {

        if(item == itemGlobal){

            theRow.mFlWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            theRow.mIvArrow.setRotation(180f);

        }else {
            theRow.mFlWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            theRow.mIvArrow.setRotation(0f);

            item.isExpanded = false;
        }

    } else {
        theRow.mFlWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        theRow.mIvArrow.setRotation(0f);


    }


    theRow.mTvTitle.setText(item.title);
    theRow.mTvDescription.setText(item.description);

    // return the view
    return convertView;
}

}
```

I achieved these requirements only the help of "inner_class7". Many many thanks to "inner_class7"